# show with php and html 130.000 records of a database with ajax functionality

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Good night, I'm trying to list in html 130.000 records, the fact is that I made the code so that it could be listed by ajax-js, and I added a feature to filter by a field of the table, however I must show 130.000 record with the functionality before said, try to use Clusterize.js, however I was not successful, since it works by dynamic creation with js, and my sun is created from the records that come from the database, the fact is that doing so, only shows 40,000 records and js does not work, know any way to solve this? I know that the page also exists but that would invalidate the search or filtered by the field, so it did not solve it by that method.

I will put a sample as a filter by the first field (so you can get an idea of why I do not solve it per page):

```
 function ocultarRegistros(nombre_buscar){
       // variable para todos los registros
       var registros = tableBody[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');

    // expresion regular que busca el nombre con case insensitive
    var expression = new RegExp(nombre_buscar, "i");

    for(var i = 0; i < registros.length;i++) {
        registros[i].classList.add('ocultar');
        registros[i].style.display = 'none';

        if(registros[i].childNodes[1].textContent.replace(/\s/g, "").search(expression) != -1 ) {
            registros[i].classList.add('mostrar');
            registros[i].classList.remove('ocultar');
            registros[i].style.display = 'table-row';
        }
    }
    actualizarNumero();
}

inputBuscador.addEventListener('input', function() {
  ocultarRegistros(this.value);
} );
```

Comment: `only shows 40,000 records and js does not work` your going to have to give more details then this.  For example are the full records returned from the server? - if they are not then the problem is with the PHP etc...  That said the obvious thing to do is page the data if it works for a smaller set. There are limits to resources especially when dealing with "unknown" client hardware.  You could have a killer laptop like me an it works just fine (for example), or you can have a phone or whatnot and it doesn't have the resources to handle that much data.  Does that mean the code is bad?

Comment: It is not a problem of php (or query) photo: https://imgur.com/kZjhWK9 , since it can counter the totality of the records that the query brings, the problem is when rendering those records, as you can see in record 41311 exactly stops rendering the html assigned photo: https://imgur.com/a/AWyVr6M

Comment: Is there any JS errors in the browser console (typically f12 debug window).

Comment: The problem is not js, since I'm using it for another section of 1200 records and it works perfectly, the problem is the amount of records which are impossible to redenrizar by the browser, I just want to know if there is any framework that serves me for virtualization but not from js if not from php.

Comment: You should use pagination, so you only return a portion of the results at a time. Most JavaScript dataframe libraries support this.

Comment: If it's possible to move this (what you are doing in JS) to the server you may be able to take the burden off the client, if you follow.  For example I have found that returning pure HTML from the server instead of returning JSON and building HTML on the client to work in cases like this.  It's much harder on the client to manipulate the DOM, then it is on the server to manipulate strings.  In any case we would need more specifics to really solve this.